# URL shortener processing URLs with PHP, then if alias doesn't exist, fall through to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using the **Phurl URL shortener**.

Has a nice UI for entering new shortened urls. Works great.

But I now want to use the same domain to host my wordpress site. So htaccess points everything to redirect ".php" with the "alias" as a param:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ redirect.php?alias=$1
```

So if I have http://example.com/tt directing to http://example.com/article-about-time-travel then "tt" will get passed to redirect.php and there will be an entry in the database for that will get turned into a 301 to the new url.

But if it's not in the database,

something like *example.com/about*  and this is a page within my wordpress site, I want that to get passed on to wordpress.

But I don't know how to do that. I don't think it's possible to put this logic in htaccess since there can be new shortened urls and new wordpress pages and other rewrites added.

**My problem is :**  I don't fully understand how rewrites work within wordpress so I can't figure out how to just pass the url on so that it can be rewritten by wordpress into something useful.

> I tried using the header() function with no success (mostly got
>   infinite redirects).

Any ideas???

Thanks to all.

EDIT: Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=2
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\w#]+)$ redirect.php?alias=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can have your `redirect.php` script just chain to WordPresses `index.php` on absent aliases. Juding from WPs default RewriteRule set it'll check the `REQUEST_URI`. You may wish to unset `$_GET["alias"]` however.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean - I've tried `header("Location: index.php", true, 301);` but that just takes me to the main front page with no params. So the _about_ isn't there and therefore that page will never get displayed. Also tried appending the alias as a param `header("Location: index.php/?$alias", true, 301);` but wp redirects are apparently not that straight-forward bc that doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to suggest is implementing the fallthrough as simple [`include()`](http://php.net/include).

Keep your [`RewriteRule`](http://www.google.com/search?q=RewriteRule) as is, and amend your existing `rewrite.php` with loading the WordPress dispatcher (`index.php`) script.

```
<?php
// --rewrite.php-- (keep yours unchanged)
if ($r = db("SELECT url FROM shortener WHERE alias=?", $_GET->text["alias"])) {
    header("Location: $r[url]");
    exit;
}

// Fall through to WordPress if nothing matched:
unset($_GET["alias"]);
include("./index.php");
?>
```

Ignore the code above, keep your rewrite.php as it is, and just append the last two lines. Just ensure that only the [`header()`](http://php.net/header)/[`http_redirect()`](http://php.net/http_redirect) call is masked by [`exit`](http://php.net/exit), and your appended logic still gets run.

That'll invoke WordPress with the current request (without internel/external redirect). WP is likely to use `REQUEST_URI` to determine which of its static pages was requested.

Comment: OK! This is good progress, thank you. It *almost* works. If I add a trailing slash to my wordpress urls then the correct page loads. But without that (the normal state), then I get the `Error establishing a database connection`. Also, I have a line that writes the alias and url to a server side file within the conditional and just "fell thru" if no match. When I get that db error, I see alias and the fall thru. When I append a slash to the url in the browser, I see nothing in the file. The slash is magical and apparently means my php file is not called. I think that has always been the case?

Comment: If that's your whole RewriteRule set, then yes; no other paths will be captured by your redirect script. Accompany it by the default WordPresss RewriteRule for other/ URLs to be recognized.

Comment: Oh - ok yeah that was dumb on my part. I had it in there and removed it at some point trying to find a solution. So adding that back in was the last missing element of the solution! Thank you!

Comment: FYI for anyone following this, after all this debugging I realized that the .htaccess part of the URL shortener is not necessary - at  least for my purposes. I deleted that in favor of `substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1)` in the PHP code.